# How to fix tableview cell and textview height dynamically using autolayouts

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am beginner in Ios in my project i am using auto-layouts for creating textview and tableview and according to my requirement tableview cell and textview height's are fixing based on text-data and in i phone4@5 it's ok but come down to iphone 6 inch some empty text space is coming but i want to remove that textview empty space and also have to decrease tableview cell height based on text data i tried my level best but it's not coming please help me

according to my code i phone 6 screen coming like second screen but i want to fix tableview cell and textview heights like first screen in all i phone inches please help me i am trying to solve this since lot of days but exact result is not coming

[image]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];



    if(indexPath.section == 1)
    {

        formulaText = [[UITextView alloc]init];
        formulaText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:15.0f];
        formulaText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        formulaText.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        formulaText.scrollEnabled = NO;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:formulaText];

        NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(formulaText);

        NSArray * formulaH = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[formulaText]-10-|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:views];

        NSArray * formulaV = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[formulaText]-|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                       views:views];

        [cell.contentView addConstraints:formulaH];
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:formulaV];

        formulaText.text = [formulaArray objectAtIndex:0];
        formulaText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:15.0];

    }

    if (indexPath.section == 2)
    {
        aboutText = [[UITextView alloc]init];
        aboutText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:15.0f];
        aboutText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        aboutText.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        aboutText.scrollEnabled = NO;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:aboutText];

        NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(aboutText);

        NSArray * formulaH = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[aboutText]-10-|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                       views:views];

        NSArray * formulaV = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[aboutText]-|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                       views:views];

        [cell.contentView addConstraints:formulaH];
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:formulaV];

        aboutText.text = [aboutArray objectAtIndex:0];
        aboutText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:15.0];

    }

    return cell;
}


- (CGSize)calculateHeightForString:(NSString *)str
{
    CGSize size = CGSizeZero;

    UIFont *labelFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f];
    NSDictionary *systemFontAttrDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:labelFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

    NSMutableAttributedString *message = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str attributes:systemFontAttrDict];
    CGRect rect = [message boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){320, MAXFLOAT}
                                        options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                        context:nil];//you need to specify the some width, height will be calculated
    size = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height + 5); //padding

    return size;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //return 200;

    if([indexPath section] == 0)
    {
        return  200;
    }

    else if([indexPath section] == 1)
    {
        NSString *cellText = [formulaArray objectAtIndex:0];
        UIFont *cellFont = [self fontForCell];
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        return labelSize.height + 20;
    }

    else
    {
        NSString *cellText = [aboutArray objectAtIndex:0];
        UIFont *cellFont = [self fontForCell];
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        return labelSize.height + 20;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the following tutorial. I won't post it as an answer, as it's not my work. http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout

Comment: Why is this tagged swift and not objective-c?

Comment: I edited this one, the same question I linked above had the same tag. Seems like there is a homework or project right now....

Answer (score 0):

Create your UITableViewCell - for instance ContinentUITableViewCell with xib. set your elements there and set autolayout as you wish. In your UITableView register it, and set reuse identifier.

Next thing is to replace your heightForRowAtIndexPath method with:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}
```

also, in your `viewDidLoad` set self.tableView.estimatedHeight to average height ( for instance 200 ).